# How do I connect to a redis database using password and ssl?

Tags: r, redis, rcpp

I'm trying to use R and RcppRedis to connect to a redis database that requires SSL and a password. I'm building the R env inside a docker container in which I compile hiredis with SSL enabled, but while I can connect to my production database I can't interact with it.

To confirm it works without a password or ssl I can connect to and interact with a local instance of redis on the same docker network using this:

```
library(RcppRedis)
r <- new(Redis, "172.18.0.4")
r$exec("keys *")

## <lots of keys print here>
```

and similarly I can connect with my production database, but I can't actually interact with it. I suspect it is because I just need to set `ssl=1`, but I don't know where, nor do I know how to send my password.

Here is what I tried:

```
redis <- new(Redis, "<my-redis-host>", port=6369, password="<my-password>", ssl="1")
## Error: Recieved NULL reply; potential connection loss with Redis


redis <- new(Redis, "<my-redis-host>", port=6369, auth="<my-password>", ssl="1")
## Error: Recieved NULL reply; potential connection loss with Redis


redis <- new(Redis, "<my-redis-host>", port=6369, ssl="1")
## Error: Recieved NULL reply; potential connection loss with Redis


redis <- new(Redis, "<my-redis-host>", port=6369)
redis$exec("auth <my-password>")
## Error: Recieved NULL reply; potential connection loss with Redis
```

I'm pretty much out of ideas. What am I missing? Is this way more complicated than I think, and I need to actually pass cert files?

EDIT:
I can demonstrate the connection requires an ssl flag using python:

```
from redis import Redis
redis = Redis(
  host="<my-redis-host>", 
  port=6369, 
  password="<my-password>", 
  ssl=True
)
redis.ping()
## True
```

From the build logs I can see that RcppRedis finds the hiredis dll file and loads its own library successfully. Relevant files below.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:latest

RUN echo "Set disable_coredump false" >> /etc/sudo.conf

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq -f \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    wget \
    nano \
    libssl-dev \
    git

RUN R -e "install.packages('Rcpp', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RApiSerialize', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('openssl', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RcppMsgPack', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

RUN git clone --branch v1.0.2 https://github.com/redis/hiredis.git &&\
  cd hiredis && \
  make USE_SSL=1 && \
  make install && \
  ldconfig

RUN R -e "install.packages('RcppRedis', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', INSTALL_opts=c('--no-lock'))"

CMD ["R", "-e", "Sys.sleep(1200)"]
```

This is the relevant block of the build log:

```
#11 [8/9] RUN git clone --branch v1.0.2 https://github.com/redis/hiredis.git &&  cd hiredis &&   make USE_SSL=1 &&   make install &&   ldconfig
#11 sha256:74cb19dc98580450d5de1e6eb18d64f812254a6857dc4d45084e545eb58a9311
#11 0.755 Cloning into 'hiredis'...
#11 2.254 Note: switching to 'b731283245f3183af527237166261ad0768ba7d4'.
#11 2.254
#11 2.254 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
#11 2.254 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
#11 2.254 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
#11 2.254
#11 2.254 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
#11 2.254 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
#11 2.254
#11 2.254   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
#11 2.254
#11 2.254 Or undo this operation with:
#11 2.254
#11 2.254   git switch -
#11 2.254
#11 2.254 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
#11 2.254
#11 2.318 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb alloc.c
#11 2.462 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb net.c
#11 3.536 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb hiredis.c
#11 4.981 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb sds.c
#11 6.000 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb async.c
#11 6.737 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb read.c
#11 7.121 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb sockcompat.c
#11 7.151 cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhiredis.so.1.0.0 -o libhiredis.so alloc.o net.o hiredis.o sds.o async.o read.o sockcompat.o
#11 7.185 ar rcs libhiredis.a alloc.o net.o hiredis.o sds.o async.o read.o sockcompat.o
#11 7.193 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb test.c
#11 8.525 cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb ssl.c
#11 8.991 ar rcs libhiredis_ssl.a ssl.o
#11 8.999 cc -o hiredis-test -O3 -fPIC  -DHIREDIS_TEST_SSL -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -ggdb -I. test.o libhiredis.a libhiredis_ssl.a  -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread
#11 9.380 Generating hiredis.pc for pkgconfig...
#11 9.431 cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhiredis_ssl.so.1.0.0  -o libhiredis_ssl.so ssl.o   -lssl -lcrypto
#11 9.732 Generating hiredis_ssl.pc for pkgconfig...
#11 9.794 mkdir -p /usr/local/include/hiredis /usr/local/include/hiredis/adapters /usr/local/lib
#11 9.801 cp -pPR hiredis.h async.h read.h sds.h alloc.h /usr/local/include/hiredis
#11 9.807 cp -pPR adapters/*.h /usr/local/include/hiredis/adapters
#11 9.816 cp -pPR libhiredis.so /usr/local/lib/libhiredis.so.1.0.0
#11 9.824 cd /usr/local/lib && ln -sf libhiredis.so.1.0.0 libhiredis.so
#11 9.830 cp -pPR libhiredis.a /usr/local/lib
#11 9.837 mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
#11 9.841 cp -pPR hiredis.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
#11 DONE 10.0s

#12 [9/9] RUN R -e "install.packages('RcppRedis', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', INSTALL_opts=c('--no-lock'))"
#12 sha256:2bcf3d61aaa393f7aed955d1ebda22a5198fe6fca9e62c03d4ec0835c7ec6a2d
#12 0.968
#12 0.968 R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
#12 0.968 Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
#12 0.968 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#12 0.968
#12 0.968 R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
#12 0.968 You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
#12 0.968 Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
#12 0.968
#12 0.969   Natural language support but running in an English locale
#12 0.969
#12 0.969 R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
#12 0.969 Type 'contributors()' for more information and
#12 0.969 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
#12 0.969
#12 0.969 Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
#12 0.969 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
#12 0.969 Type 'q()' to quit R.
#12 0.969
#12 1.120 > install.packages('RcppRedis', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', INSTALL_opts=c('--no-lock'))
#12 1.125 Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
#12 1.125 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
#12 3.952 trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppRedis_0.2.3.tar.gz'
#12 4.208 Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1066907 bytes (1.0 MB)
#12 4.208 ==================================================
#12 4.703 downloaded 1.0 MB
#12 4.703
#12 5.706 * installing *source* package ‘RcppRedis’ ...
#12 5.720 ** package ‘RcppRedis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#12 5.721 staged installation is only possible with locking
#12 5.721 ** using non-staged installation
#12 6.339 checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
#12 6.562 checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
#12 6.564 checking for suffix of executables...
#12 6.823 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#12 7.101 checking for suffix of object files... o
#12 7.156 checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
#12 7.206 checking whether g++ -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... yes
#12 7.252 checking for g++ -std=gnu++14 option to enable C++11 features... none needed
#12 7.727 checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++14 -E
#12 8.109 checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... (cached) yes
#12 8.111 checking whether g++ -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... (cached) yes
#12 8.114 checking for g++ -std=gnu++14 option to enable C++11 features... (cached) none needed
#12 8.118 checking for pkg-config... yes
#12 8.156 checking for stdio.h... yes
#12 8.275 checking for stdlib.h... yes
#12 8.419 checking for string.h... yes
#12 8.544 checking for inttypes.h... yes
#12 8.705 checking for stdint.h... yes
#12 8.819 checking for strings.h... yes
#12 8.909 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
#12 8.997 checking for sys/types.h... yes
#12 9.096 checking for unistd.h... yes
#12 9.265 checking for hiredis/hiredis.h... yes
#12 9.469 checking for RcppMsgPack... yes
#12 10.45 configure: Found RcppMsgPack, using '-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppMsgPack/include -DHAVE_MSGPACK'
#12 10.48 configure: creating ./config.status
#12 10.62 config.status: creating src/Makevars
#12 10.65
#12 10.65 RcppRedis 0.2.3
#12 10.65 ================
#12 10.65
#12 10.65 compiler flags:  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/hiredis -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppMsgPack/include -DHAVE_MSGPACK
#12 10.65 link argument:   -L/usr/local/lib -lhiredis
#12 10.65 library target:
#12 10.65
#12 10.71 ** libs
#12 10.71 g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RApiSerialize/include'   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/hiredis -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppMsgPack/include -DHAVE_MSGPACK -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-a1ov7y/r-base-4.2.1=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c Redis.cpp -o Redis.o
#12 36.58 gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RApiSerialize/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-a1ov7y/r-base-4.2.1=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c init.c -o init.o
#12 36.70 g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppRedis.so Redis.o init.o -L/usr/local/lib -lhiredis -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
#12 45.49 installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppRedis/libs
#12 45.50 ** R
#12 45.51 ** demo
#12 45.51 ** inst
#12 45.52 ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
#12 46.14 ** help
#12 46.16 *** installing help indices
#12 46.19 ** building package indices
#12 46.47 ** installing vignettes
#12 46.48 ** testing if installed package can be loaded
#12 47.97 * DONE (RcppRedis)
#12 48.02
#12 48.02 The downloaded source packages are in
#12 48.02       ‘/tmp/RtmpAGjyAc/downloaded_packages’
#12 48.02 >
#12 48.02 >
```

Comment: Try to break down exactly _how_ you can connect to the Redis backend in terms of port and protocol (just saying "needs ssl" is a bit vague) and then see if `hiredis` supports it.  Rcpp is not doing anything here ... besides faithfully putting together all the individual pieces doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

RcppRedis uses [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis), which is *the* standard C library for Redis access.

If you go to the [documentation of the hiredis API](https://redis.com/lp/hiredis/) you find a section named *Using SSL and hiredis" stating

> hiredis does not support SSL connections natively. For an added security measure, you can secure the connection using stunnel.

which explains why you had no luck.

Comment: thanks for the comment and the answer. my soft interpretation of this is that its not officially supported, but somebody must have success with the make flag USE_SSL=1 or else it would be removed?

Comment: Could you share where you saw that (I presume environment variable) described and shown?   Either way, as I already stated: RcppRedis is made possible by hiredis. If hiredis does not do it, I cannot enable it.  The hint about doing it inside an ssh tunnel is not a bad one.

Comment: I think it was indeed removed from the ReadMe file! last year I tried this same connection and `make USE_SSL=1` was documented in the readme. Now as you point out it suggests stunnel. The code to use the make flag is still present in redis/hiredis/Makefile (starting on line 68), but given the removal of documentation I guess that feature is effectively dead. 
I'm looking into stunnel now, it sounds promising but has not actually connected for me yet. I'm going to edit the original question with how I can demonstrate to myself that I can connect with python's Redis package.

Comment: Sounds good.  And while _most_ of my Redis are on the local network, I has this need once too and (if memory serves) did just that: set up a tunnel via `ssh`, used it therein.  More fiddly, but what can you do.  If the library had the feature we'd happily support it but the way things stand that's not an option.

Comment: Also, of course, if you suspect / know that older `hiredis` versions had that you could try building with those.  From the R / Rcpp there should be little difference: you just call a library entry point.

Comment: yes, I did try an older hiredis release also without success. Here is another way of phrasing my question: When I add arguments such as `new(Redis, password=<my_password>, ssl=1)` , does RcppRedis pass them to hiredis? If so do you recall how it is used by hiredis? I suspect they are not included in the setting up the connection context, but I don't know enough about c or c++ to see how they are or even should be used.

Comment: No, randomly injecting arguments you do not see in the corresponding source code do not randomly alter said code.  At the RcppRedis level I do not believer we ever had an argument `ssl=...`.    "Wishing alone does not make it so."  Now, _if_ the underlying library supports it _then_ you can glance at the one-file (albeit Rcpp Modules so a little tricky) implementation and add yourself an accessor.